# Cannot read property 'require' (Electron)

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy haciendo una aplicacion de escritorio en electron pero cuando uso el 'remote' me salta este error 'Cannot read property 'require', ayuda porfavor

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
const main = remote.require('./main'); //Cannot read property 'require'
```

Esto lo hago para exportar mi funcion:

```
module.exports ={
    createProduct
}
```

Aqui es donde la quiero usar:

```
productForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newProduct = {
        nameProduct: nameInput.value,
        priceProduct: priceInput.value,
        descriptionProduct: descriptionInput.value
    }

    main.createProduct(newProduct); //Aqui la usaria

})
```

Comment: La respuesta es simple, nodeJS y javascript no son lo mismo exactamente, para que te funcione require debe ser en un script ejecutado por nodeJS, ya que javascript puro no contiene la sentencia require.

Comment: La forma en que estás usando el objeto `remote` no sería la adecuada. Prueba con: `const main = require('electron').remote.require('./main');`. Luego podrías usar tu función con: `main.createProduct(newProduct);` tal como tienes planeado hacerlo. Saludos